# Using phonegap, what is a good way to store data?

Tags: cordova

I'm using phonegap 2.2.0.
I download data to the app, in JSON format, from my server.

Data is stored in a mySQL database and I use PHP on the server to connect to the database.

Each data record consists of about 10 different fields, mainly shorter strings, some
may be longer. I.e., I have a description field which may contain 256 chars.

There may be around a thousand records which I want to retrieve from the database. Just an estimate, but probably not much more.

What would be a good way to handle this data? Is it small enough to be kept in memory in my phonegap app? If not, what is to be preferred for persisting:

- local storage
- or the file API?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I also created a PhoneGap application that retrieves data from a remote database. If the WiFi connection is down, the app retrieves the data saved locally on the device. The files was save as filename.json (json format) when the last WiFi connection was available. The localStorage object was also used so each page of the app can have access to the data without re-reading the same file again to improve the performance of the app.

Comment: Checking out [this phonegap SQL Lite plugin](https://github.com/brodyspark/PhoneGap-SQLitePlugin-iOS). I understand this may be a good one. Especially if data may exceed 5 mb.

Comment: I've gotten feedback on Twitter from an expert on the subject. He says this amount of data may be kept in memory without problem. So, if offline support is not needed, this would be the way to go.

Comment: Sounds good! Do you need to do sychronisation between your device database and server database?

Comment: Well, somehow yes. I thought maybe an explicit update button could do the trick. Do you have a suggestion for server-to-device-synch?

Comment: I just read up a bit on the subject. Conditional get, perhaps combined with a reasonable value for 'Expires' seem to be a nice way of caching ajax requests. (this is moving somewhat out of this questions scope)

Comment: Yep, I used Jquery.getJSON to retrieve data from remote database and this function returns JSON object. This link(http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) has the function API. getJSON is the shorthand of .ajax()!